# meaning of awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] "," $2} END {for (i in a) print a[i]}'

Tags: arrays, for-loop, awk

Can you please help me to understand this command line:

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] "," $2} END {for (i in a) print a[i]}'
```

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so please do add the same and let us know.

Comment: You're probably missing `$` in front of `1` in `a[1]`, otherwise it's nonsense.

Comment: Oh, yes I am sorry

Comment: Are you asking what it does, or how it does what it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{a[$1]=a[$1] "," $2}` accumulates second fields of lines by matching first fields

`END {for (i in a) print a[i]}` at the end of processing prints the accumulated fields per key line by line.

Problems I see

- the initial dangling comma.
- the printed values won't indicate which key they correspond to